# How long does eth.sendTransaction take?

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp

Sorry if this type of question has been asked before, but I have not found any questions dealing with this scenario. I am using Geth and am kind of new to this thing. I bought some Ether on Coinbase a while back and initiated a transfer to my Geth account address from Coinbase and was able to see that it [successfully occurred](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x7539ba66e560d0ea44c9708c4d7966ce952ff5e92478461f1307bfb979517600).

Now, I want send that amount back to my Coinbase address and I used the following command in the Geth console (replacing `xxx` with the actual addresses):

```
eth.sendTransaction({from: '0xAf2999f18d582086Ce62209ef4701E6F23066C1C', to: '0x7DD98A5581c3d9BA1dfF9C7894368Cb434351B7C', value: web3.toWei(5, "ether")}
```

This has been running for probably 30 minutes and the only output I have received from the Geth console are three periods (`...`). It is important to note that I have not fully synchronized with the Blockchain (because it will take several more days, due to disk I/O) and the console still shows some block updates while this is still running:

[image]

Geth also showed a balanced of 0 ETH before I sent the transaction. I know that my address has 5 ETH due to the confirmation I can see on etherscan.io.

Will this transaction ever resolve? If not, is it safe to CTRL + C out of it? When would I be able to actually send out a transaction?

I tried using Ethereum Wallet, but when I pressed send, nothing actually happened. Similar, Ethereum Wallet wanted me to create a contract to view my balance, but that contract had a cost associated with it, so I did not proceed with that.

Comment: Hi Mark. Things aren't going to "catch up" and look right until the chain is synced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Important:**

With commands like this, especially if this is the first time you've tried it, it's always better to test things out using a *small* amount of ether.

---

The actual problem is that you're missing the closing bracket on your command. Each opening bracket (parenthesis), and each curly bracket needs an equivalent closing bracket. You need another `)` at the end. I'd cancel this command using `ctrl + c` and try re-running it.

---

As an alternative, you could use something like myetherwallet.com

Comment: I can't believe I was missing the closing parentheses. Did not even notice it. Thanks!

Comment: If I try to send a small amount, I get the error `Insufficient funds for gas * price + value`. I assume this is because my blockchain is not fully synchronized and it does not know I have ETH in this address yet. Is that correct?

Comment: You have to cover the gas cost of the transaction itself (the transaction fee). The default fee is 21,000 wei, so try specifying something a bit larger than that.